# Bus error in C struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, bus

This is a code I testing to copying struct.

```
 1 #include <stdio.h>
 2 #include <string.h>
 3 
 4 typedef struct emp_struct {
 5     char *name;
 6     int employee_no;
 7     float salary,
 8           tax_to_date;
 9 } Employee;
 10 
 11 typedef Employee Database[10];
 12 
 13 Database people = {
 14     {"Fred", 10, 10000, 3000},
 15     {"Jim", 9, 12000, 3100.5},
 16     {"Fred", 13, 1000000, 30},
 17     {"Mary", 11, 170000, 4000},
 18     {"Judith", 45, 130000, 50000},
 19     {"Nigel", 10, 5000, 1200},
 20     {"Trevor", 10, 20000, 6000},
 21     {"Karen", 10, 120000, 34000},
 22     {"Marianne", 10, 50000, 12000},
 23     {"Mildred", 10, 100000, 30000}
 24 };
 25 
 26 int main () {
 27     // array act like pointer, thus pointing + pointing = ERROR
 28     printf("people[1]->name: ERROR\n");
 29     // jump its memory amount of struct size
 30     printf("(people+1)->name:%s\n",(people+1)->name);
 31     // array works as a pointer
 32     printf("people[3].name:%s\n",people[3].name);
 33 
 34     /* Is it possible to assign struct to struct? */
 35     printf("\nAssigning struct to struct\n");
 36     Employee temp;
 37     temp = *(people+5); // Nigel Record
 38     printf("Name: %s\n",temp.name);
 39     // exchange
 40     strcpy(temp.name, "Ahn");
 41     printf("Changed: %s\n",temp.name);
 42     printf("Original: %s\n",people[5].name);
 43 
 44     return 0;
 45 }
```

When I tried to **strcpy(new, string)** in line 40, then it throws out **Bus error: 10**.

I expected that value **Changed** and **Original** are same in line 41 and 42. But it would not work. What is the problem of assigning?

I knew that Bus error:10 is occurred by lack of assignment space. But my **name** field in struct is pointer (in line 5). If I changed name field like

```
 char name[100];
```

It works properly and **Changed** and **Original** value are different! Even though I assigned that as a pointer.

What is the problem of this struct assigning?

Comment: You never allocate memory for `temp.name`, and the value within the database points to what should be considered constant data.  If you attempt to write to that area, anything can happen; your OS apparently just chose to trigger a SIGBUS.

Comment: @cHao. I already tried temp->name like pointer assigning, but it throws out referencing error. Then it makes sense that assigning *name field in 'malloc' way.

Comment: @cHao I tried to use `char *name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);` and it works. You're right. I think vague assigning memory always occurring error. Thanks!

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers.  You can't assign an array (except when defining it), but you can `strcpy` into it.  You can assign pointers virtually at will, but it's on you if you try to do something wacky with them (like `strcpy`ing over a read-only region of memory).

Comment: Why don't you use `people[5]` instead of `*(people+5)`.  It's more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

temp.name is a pointer to char.
After the copy `temp = *(people+5);`,  temp.name is pointing to the bytes containing "Nigel".

So far, no problem. But you can't use that pointer as the output for strcpy(); strcpy will try to overwrite it, and it's stored in read-only memory.

You can do this:

temp.name = "Ahn";

... since all that you are doing here is changing the pointer (temp.name) to point to a different area of memory which is set up in advance to contain "Ahn".

This is actually nothing to do with struct copying.
You will have the same problem if you try to do `strcpy(people[3].name, "Ahn")`

Answer (score 1):

When you declared the Database record, all the names(Fred, Jim, Fred ...) were put in the `read-only` memory of the data segment and the `name` character pointer pointed to their starting addresses.

When you do `strcpy(temp.name, "Ahn");`, you are trying to write in the read-only. Trying to write into `read-only` memory will cause a bus error.

The solution would be to allocate memory for the `name` and then do the `strcpy`. Also a good programming practice is to use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`